# Class not finding when using XamlCompositionBrushBase

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-composition-api

So I tried to use BackdropBrush with XamlCompositionBrushBase creating a class called BackdropBlurBrush, but when I call it from XAML  It doesn’t find the class.
I created the class on the main project. 
[See the error here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yygGv.jpg)

Sample on GitHub: https://github.com/vitorgrs/HostBackdrop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom composition brush is **not** a `UIElement` and that's why it cannot be placed onto the XAML visual tree directly.

Try adding it as a brush for an element -

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <local:BackdropBlurBrush BlurAmount="5" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

You normally want to place your blur brush on top of your background image like this -

```
<Grid x:Name="Root">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="background.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <local:BackdropBlurBrush BlurAmount="5" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Now it makes sense. :) When I saw the error, I just thought it was not finding the class itself, and not that it wasn't supposed to work there. I forgot that, well, it's a brush. 
Thanks. :)